# What's wrong with my MPMediaPlayerController?

Tags: ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

Hi all
I've create simple movie player in iPhone development. But i got just only vedio's voice.
Here is my code (when button click),

```
-(IBAction)playMe{
    NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath=[bundle pathForResource:@"iiii" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    [theMovie play];
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
}
```

When i click i got only voice not with movie. I also used iOS 4.1 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

it may be because of you have not set frame to display movie player try this.

```
theMovie.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,300.400);
```

If this does not work
you  can check out following tutorials

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-play-video-in-iphoneos4/

http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44642/1954

http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/how-to-play-movies-from-application-bundle-or-from-a-remote-server-url.html